# How to hide sidebar in start page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sidebar

I use template from AdminLTE and I want to hide the sidebar on start page. I have  tried to add the `class="toggled"` on wrapper tag but it doesn't work. 
How to hide the sidebar on start page?

[image]

Comment: `$('#mySidebar').hide()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]You need to add class `sidebar-collapse` to the body of the html.

if you're using jQuery try the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse");
});
```